# Gitlab CI: Docker connect to remote MySQL via SSH Portforwarding before running tests

Tags: docker, ssh, gitlab-ci

I am trying to integrate my unit tests into Gitlab CI, which is mostly working.

The NodeJS application uses MySQL databases hosted on a different server (using: `ssh -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 username@remoteserver`) which we locally port forward to, and as such, all the tests pass locally as we are connected to it.

The CI script (included below) seems to work and the tests pass on any function that doesn't require the mysql connection. I need my CI runner to SSH into the remote server and let those remaining functions be tested.

However, I am struggling to find a way to have my `gitlab-ci.yml` script execute the SSH (using a public key) into this remote server and locally port forward it to 127.0.0.1, before the tests are run.

I also am unsure as to whether the public/private key pair is to be generated inside Docker, or generally on the machine that the Runner is set up on.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
image: node:7.4

before_script:
  - apt-get update -qy
  - npm install -g mocha chai assert mysql require moment
stages:
  - test

test_job:
  stage: test
  tags: ["mySpecificRunner"]
  script:
    - npm run test

  environment:

  only:
  - development
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not straight forward, but there is a way. GitLab provides [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/ssh_keys/README.html) and even an [example](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/ssh-private-key/blob/e517e4cac941d38b5ec7a03bd35945bcd64a7852/.gitlab-ci.yml).

What you want to do is:

1. Generate a public/private key pair
2. On the server you want to connect to, add the public part of the key to the file listing the authorized ones (usually `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`)
3. In Gitlab, create a new variable called `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` with the private part of the key as value
4. In your project, modify the file `.gitlab-ci.yml` so that the Docker container uses the private part of the key:

   ```
   image: debian:latest

   before_script:
   # install & run ssh-agent
   - apt-get -qq update -y
   - apt-get -qq install openssh-client -y
   # setup the private key
   - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
   - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
   - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
   - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
   ```
5. You script should then be able to connect seamlessly to the server and run commands or scripts there, e.g.(`$HOST` and `$USER` are also secret variables):

   ```
   deploy-dev:
     stage: deploy
     script:
     - |
       ssh -t $USER@$HOST << EOF
         git fetch --all -v
         git checkout -f dev
         git reset --hard origin/dev
         EOF
   ```

Note that at the time of writing this answer I have been unable to keep the SSH connection active and run commands one by one there. That is the reason behind the use `<< EOF`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your detailed response! Now I have the weekend to try out and get this working! Will report back shortly

Comment: This works a treat. One thing I had to do was add the public key as a deploy key too, as I was getting a host key checking error.

I also add " || exit 1" after critical lines (especially in the deploy/publish stages when we get to npm) to forcibly fail the build stage if anything goes wrong